# How to find equal values in different fields in Elasticsearch via Python Query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, networkx

I've got values in Elasticsearch (+Kibana) and want to make a Graph, where certain nodes are connected.

My fields are "prev" and "curr" and indicate the "previous" and the "current" page, which the user visited.

E.g:

- prev: Main_Page, curr: Donald_Trump
- prev: other-internal, curr: El_Bienamado
- ...

So what I'm trying to do is searching for values, where current is equal to previous, to be able to connect those and visualize via Networkx-Graph in Kibana.

My problem is that I just started yesterday with query-syntax and don't know if this is even possible.
All in all, my goal is to make a graph, where nodes are connected to a chain, e.g:

- Main_Page -> Donald_Trump -> Problems_in_Afrika -> etc.

Meaning that somebody visited those pages in a certain order.

What I've tried for now is:

```
def getPrevList():
    previous = []
    previousQuery = {
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
            "topTerms": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "prev",
                    "size": 50000
                }
            }
        }
    }
    results = es.search(index="wiki", body=previousQuery)["aggregations"]["topTerms"]["buckets"]
    for bucket in results:
        previous.append({
            "prev" : bucket["key"],
            "numDocs" : bucket["doc_count"]
        })
    return previous

prevs=getPrevList()

rowNum = 0;
totalNumReviews=0

for prevDetails in prevs:
    rowNum += 1
    totalNumDocs += prevDetails["numDocs"]
    prevId = prevDetails["prev"]

    q = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {"prev": prevId}
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "controls": {
            "sample_size": 10000,
            "use_significance": True
        },
        "vertices": [
            {
                "field": "curr",
                "size": VERTEX_SIZE,
                "min_doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "field": "prev",
                "size": VERTEX_SIZE,
                "min_doc_count": 1
            }
        ],
        "connections": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

At the end, I'm doing the following:

```
results = es.transport.perform_request('POST', "/wiki/_xpack/_graph/_explore", body=q)  

# Use NetworkX to create a graph of prevs and currs we can analyze
G = nx.Graph()

for node in results["vertices"]:
    G.add_node(nodeId(node), type=node["field"])

for edge in results["connections"]:
    n1 = results["vertices"][int(edge["source"])]
    n2 = results["vertices"][int(edge["target"])]
    G.add_edge(nodeId(n1), nodeId(n2))
```

I copied it from another example, which worked well, but I can see that the "connections" are important to be able to connect the vertices.

As far as I understood, I need the query to find the correct "prev" field.
The controls are not significant for now.
And here comes the complex part for me: What am I writing in the vertices and connections part? Is it correct that I defined vertices as the prev and curr fields?
And in the connections-query: for now I defined "match_all", but this is obviously not correct. I need a query, where I can "match" those, where prev equals curr and connect them.. but HOW??

Any hint is appreciated!
Thank you in forward.

**EDIT**:

Like @Lupanoide suggested, I altered the code and have now two visualizations:
the first one is the first suggested solution and it gives me this graph (part of it) (matplotlib, not Kibana yet):

[image: dict2Graph]

The second solution looks more crazy and is more likely to be the correct one, but I need to visualize it in Kibana first:

[image: two for-loops]

So the new end of my script is now:

```
gq = json.dumps(q)

workspaceID ="/f44c95c0-223d-11e9-b49e-bb0f8e1e7bae" # my v6.4.0 workspace

workspaceUrl = "graph#/workspace/"+workspaceID+"?query=" + urllib.quote_plus(gq)        
doc = {
    "url": workspaceUrl
}
res = es.index(index=connectionsIndexName, doc_type='task', id=0, body=doc)
```

My only problem now is that when I'm using Kibana to open the URL, I do not see the graph. Instead I get the "new Graph" page.

**EDIT2**
Okay, I send the query, but of course the query alone is not enough. I need to pass the graph and its connections, right? Is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
For your use case you need find all the values for field `curr` with the same `prev` value. So you need to groupBy all the pages that are clicked after a certain page. You can do that with [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) .
You need to build a query that on one hand returns, with a term aggregation, all the values for the `prev` field and then you aggregate against over all the `curr` values generated:

```
def getOccurrencyDict():

  body = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "getAllThePrevs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "prev",
        "size": 40000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "getAllTheCurr": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "curr",
            "size": 40000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
result = es.search(index="my_index", doc_type="mydoctype", body=body)
```

Then you have to build a data structure that the `class Graph()` of `Networkx` library accepts. So you should build a dict of list and then pass that var to the [fromdictoflist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists.html#networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists) method:

```
dict2Graph = dict()
for res in result["aggregations"]["getAllThePrevs"]["buckets"]:
    dict2Graph[ res["key"] ] = list() #you create a dict of list with a prev value key
    dict2Graph[ res["key"] ].append(res["getAllTheCurr"]["buckets"]) # you append a list of dict composed by key `key` with the `curr` value, and key `doc_count` with the number of occurrence of the term `curr` before the term prev
```

Now you pass it to the networkx ingestion method:

```
G=nx.from_dict_of_lists(dict2Graph)
```

I have not tested the networkx ingestion, so if it doesn't work , it is because we passed a dict of list of dict inside it and not a dict of list, so you should change a little bit how you build your `dict2Graph` dict

If the aggregation of aggregation query is too slow you should use prtition. Please [read here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) how you could reach partition aggregation in elastic

## EDIT:

after a reading of the networkX documentation, you could do also in this way, without creating the intermediate data structure:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.client.graph import GraphClient

es = Elasticsearch()
graph_client = GraphClient(es) 

def createGraphInKibana(prev):
    q = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"prev": prev}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "controls": {
        "sample_size": 10000,
        "use_significance": True
    },
    "vertices": [
        {
            "field": "curr",
            "size": VERTEX_SIZE,
            "min_doc_count": 1
        },
        {
            "field": "prev",
            "size": VERTEX_SIZE,
            "min_doc_count": 1
        }
    ],
    "connections": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
       }
    }
    graph_client.explore(index="your_index", doc_type="your_doc_type", body=q)





G = nx.Graph()
for prev in result["aggregations"]["getAllThePrevs"]["buckets"]:
    createGraphInKibana(prev['key'])
    for curr in prev["getAllTheCurr"]["buckets"]:
        G.add_edge(prev["key"], curr["key"], weight=curr["doc_count"])
```

Comment: Hello again @Lupanoide :) I think I didn't make it clear enough. So I never have a document, where prev and curr are the same. It only happens with different documents. Meaning e.g. I have (prev,curr) = (A,B) and another doc with (B,C) and now I'm searching for a query, so I can connect A->B->C in the network. I thought, maybe somehow I can find all fields starting with (A,\*) and from there look at the * as (*,#) and so on.. And yes, prev and curr are keyword datatypes. Additionally I don't have one "my_value" but nearly 40000, but I surely can iterate over them, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer, too :) Thank you for helping! I know, the answer is complete, but maybe you know the answer to my last question in the edit part?

Comment: @Nin4ikP I'm glad to help you. For the last question, We could investigate. After you try to open the url from browser - do you mean this when you say <b>using Kibana to open the URL</b>? - you should run tail /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log and post the output

Comment: Ah, no. I mean this: I'm trying to send the connected graph to kibana, but I reused another code and it doesn't fit, because the other code sends requests, but mine (or better yours) aggregates the fields. What I actually need is an request, that connects the same nodes in Kibana as it does in the nx-graph. I'm trying to find out now. I'll tell you, if I find out how to do that :)

Comment: Look at here: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/xpack.html?highlight=graph#graph-explore

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've tried earlier! I'll update my question, when I've found out the correct "body" :)

Comment: sorry @Nin4ikP I have seen only now your second edit. Hope I haven't create problems. Your query to insert edges in Graph seems to be correct according the documentation, but I haven't tryied it. I have only call the right client. Send me a feedback, please. ciao :)